# Specify nosetests working directory

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this documentation](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin_add_nosetests), it is possible to specify a working directory for the nosetests. I want the nosetests to run in the build directory, so I tried the following:

```
catkin_add_nosetests(test WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```

This is not working, however. When I print the current directory in a nosetest using

```
print "working directory: ", os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)
```

the result is still the source directory where the tests are defined.

I am still using groovy, so maybe this parameter is not yet implemented in groovy? Or am I using the working_directory parameter wrongly?

In any case, is there a way to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210290/specify-nosetests-working-directory/) by [luator](https://answers.ros.org/users/21035/luator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2015-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The  `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option does not work when you specify a directory as the first argument. Then that directory is implicitly used by `nosetests` as the cwd. If you want to specify a different cwd you need to specify the test files explicitly.

I have updated the docblock to mention this: https://github.com/ros/catkin/commit/f8e742d8693f126238e8579b03b3f37f0bcd5600

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1